# STRATO: Is providing your own authoritative DNS server possible?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-registrar, authoritative

I am thinking about transferring my domain to STRATO (https://www.strato.de/).
I have my own / external DNS server which I want to use as an authoritative DNS server.
Sadly, the help pages do not specifically say if you can change the authoritative DNS address of the domain from their own DNS (which only supports a limited set of DNS records) to another external one.

Can someone who knows the STRATO service tell if it is possible to change the authoritative DNS there or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible. I have a domain at Strato for which I configured custom NS records.

[image: Strato NS configuration]